# Is it possible to see if Zend Framework is instantiated?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Lets say I had an application using version 2.0.0 of the framework and I wanted to then use version 2.1.x in the same application, for what ever reason. Now Zend might conflict based on configuration so while your calling a class that might be in 2.0 you might actually call the one in 2.1.x (we don't want this, just yet - also if you try and instantiate the auto loader, I believe - untested - that Zend will say - this class is already instantiated).

So the question is, is there a way to say "hey have I instantiated, set up or other wise configured Zend Framework 2.0? if so lets use that, if not, lets use 2.1.x"

I ask this because I would to test running multiple versions of a framework, such as zend, in the same project and have the project "intelligently" choose which one to use based on configurations and instantiation of the framework.

Comment: ZF is just a bunch of php files. You can bring a required one together with your project. Keeping in mind what I just said - it's not clear how to answer on the question: what is for ZF to be installed? If there is a ZF instance located in `/tmp` - do you treat it as "installed"?

Comment: Usually when you bring in ZF to a project you instantiate the auto loader to load the classes and so on. but what happens if I bring in two zf's of different versions and configure them both to run - it will freak out. so how do we say "hey ones already instantiated" ...

Comment: so if **you** bring 2 versions - who do you want to ask about it? You have already brought them, haven't you?

Comment: I want to ask zend if its autoloadeer is already instantiated

Comment: `spl_autoload_functions()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do:

```
class_exists('Zend\Version\Version');
```

From your comment it sounds like you might be trying to distribute an application and want to bundle ZF with it, but I would suggest not doing this - just let Composer handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the real question is how to test a website against different versions of Zend.

Typically the Zend framework is simply loaded from the include path specified in the PHP ini file **at the time the client requests the page**.

For example from one of my websites I have in my php.ini file:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/zend/library"
```

and in my index.php:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

So that the **PHP engine** eventually looks to find Autoloader.php in

```
/usr/local/zend/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php
```

So for different framework versions you would just need different include paths, so that when the page was called a decision is made to search through either:

```
/usr/local/ZendFramework-2.0/library/...
```

or

```
/usr/local/ZendFramework-2.1/library/...
```

There are at least a couple of ways you could do this:

1. Hack the index.php file to *adjust* the PHP include path based on some external reference .
2. (For apache) Hack the .htaccess file to *adjust* the PHP include path based on some external reference

Personally I would choose method #2 and use an environment variable to determine which PHP include path was set, so you are not changing your website code just to do testing.